# Link in Email to a Google URL not working

Tags: html, user-interface, google-apps-script, google-apps, google-forms

I'm trying to create a simple workflow using Google Forms which sends an automated e-mail for approval.

```js
function sendEmail(e){
  var requestorEmail = e.values[1];
  Logger.log('replyEmail: ' + requestorEmail);
  var SupervisorsEmail = e.values[2]; //manager e-mail
  var ApplicationID = e.values[3];
  var ApplicationDate = e.values[4]; //dateconfirmationSent
  var ApplicantName = e.values[5]; //interpreter name
  var MBO = e.values[6];
  var Processor = e.values[7];
  var ShortReason = e.values[8];
  var ReasonCode = e.values[9];
  var approval = e.values[10];  //the one we need to modify
  var url ='https://script.google.com/a/macros/bbva.com/s/AKfycbz5GL9xxSmRcDjUFRJdn4qw7TrfaWNUFD8XwHNlqsCxNPRpOd49/exec';


  /**might be that the & needs to be a ?*/
  var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'?reply='+requestorEmail;
  var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'?reply='+requestorEmail;

  var html = "<HTML><body>"+
           "<h2>Pend Request</h2><br />"
  +"<P>" + ApplicationID +"  " + ApplicationDate
  +"<p>" + "MBO: "+ MBO  
  +"<p>" + "Processor: " + Processor
  +"<p>" + "Short Reason: "+ ShortReason
  +"<p>" + "requester: "+ requestorEmail
  +"<p>" + "Reason Code: "+ ReasonCode+ "  "+
   "<p>"+

   "<a href="+ approve +">Approve</a><br />"+
   "<p>"+

   "<a href=" +reject+">Reject</a><br />"+
          "</HTML></body>";

  MailApp.sendEmail(SupervisorsEmail, "Approval Request", "what no html?", {htmlBody: html});

  }

function doGet(e) {

 var app = UiApp.createApplication();
 var requestorEmail = e.values[1];
  Logger.log('replyEmail: ' + requestorEmail);

 var aprovalResponce = (e.parameter.approval == 'true') ? 'Approved.' : 'Sorry, your request has been denied.';

  var msg = "Your manager said :" + aprovalResponce;

  //var replyEmail = e.values[1];
 //Logger.log(replyEmail);

  MailApp.sendEmail(requestorEmail, "Approval Request", msg);

  var helloWorldLabel = app.createLabel(msg);
  app.add(helloWorldLabel);


  return app;
}
```

When i run the actual program, everything works fine. But when i receive the e-mail, whether I click approve or reject, I receive an "Invalid email:undefined" error. I'm new to GAS and have researched a lot of tutorials, examples, etc. But it's few that are helpful since the big changes that were recently made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the second question mark in the URL to an ampersand.  What you have now:

```
var approve = url + '?approval=true'+'?reply='+requestorEmail;
var reject = url + '?approval=false'+'?reply='+requestorEmail;
```

Change:

```
+'?reply='
```

To:

```
+'&reply='
```

Comment: You fixed it again! Thanks!